# Tumblr API not retrieving photo captions

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api, tumblr

I am using the Tumblr API to produce a image feed on my site.

I can get the photos and their URLs ok, but not the captions.

I have made a script that simply loops through posts as such:

success: function(results){

```
var i = 0;

 while (i < results.response.posts.length) {

    if (type == "photo") {
     var photourl = results.response.posts[i].photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url;
     var caption = results.response.posts[i].caption;

     $("#tumnews #newscara").append("<li><div class='tumpost'><a href='" + link + "'><img src='" + photourl + "' alt='" + title + "'/><div class='tumcaption'>" + caption + "</div></a></div></li>");
   }

  i++;
 }//END WHILE
```

But I just cannot retrieve the data for captions, even though the docs say it simply retrives with the term 'caption' (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#photo-posts).

I have also tried:

```
  var caption = results.response.posts[i].photos[0].caption;
```

and

```
  var caption = results.response.posts[i]photos[0].caption[0];
```

But I dont get any results - not even any errors.

Would anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the documentation

> Photo objects with properties: caption – string: user supplied caption
>   for the individual photo (Photosets only)

The code you are trying relates to the caption for a single photo of **Photoset** post.

`var caption = results.response.posts[i].photos[0].caption`

Your code seems to suggest your dealing with a **Photo** post not a **Photoset** post, so you would use the following:

`var caption = results.response.posts[i].caption`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would do the loop using $.each() since you use JQuery :

```
success: function(results){
  console.log(results); // <-- This is your best friend

  $.each(results.response.posts, function(k, post){
    if (type == "photo") {
     var photourl = post.photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url;
     var caption = post.caption;
     $("#tumnews #newscara").append("<li><div class='tumpost'><a href='" + link + "'><img src='" + photourl + "' alt='" + title + "'/><div class='tumcaption'>" + caption + "</div></a></div></li>");
    }
  });

}
```

And if you're not retrieving the expecting results from the API, please just try console.log(results); to see what kind of data you're working with in Firebug or another Web inspecter.